# Item in top link not visible

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a sharepoint online team site with approx 90 subsites in it. All of these are added in the top link menu and visible to me as owner.
Other people in my organization have contribute rights and are able to see all links, except for one. They do have the rights to navigate to the subsite, it is just the link which isn't showing. Any idea where to look and how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Did the issue only occur on one user?

To troubleshoot the issue, check things below:

1. Check the permission of the user in the parent site again.
2. Grant the contribution permission to the user directly to check if the same issue will occur.
3. Clear IE cache. And then sign out and sign in with the user.